# using transform each to rotate multiple items, and they keep moving for some reason when I don't need them to

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform, rotate, error, glitch

I am using Command + Shift + Alt + D to get Transform each on some items I want rotated by 180 degrees.
[image: initial items needed to be rotated, before Transform Each]

When the dialog is open, the items move away for some reason, though they have not been moved yet by me. See before & after:
[image: before rotating]

[image: after rotating]

If I hit OK to close the dialog box, they remain rotated but moved away (which I don't need). If I select individually to transform, it works just fine. The items I am working with in particular are clipping masks to hold all the contents (the image of the person, the vertical text, the purple bar, etc). Any ideas why this is happening and how I can possibly change/prevent the items from moving? I have like 50 more of these and would be easier with Transform Each option

Comment: I will assume you are referring to the "purple bar" -- you don't make it clear *what* seems to be moving in the question. The "purple bar" is still there when rotated, it's merely that the *blending mode* associated with it has a different appearance because the underlying image is different on the right side compared to the left side. Note the jacket/blazer... the bar is still there.

Comment: It may also be that that purple bar has a gradient fill and the gradient is rotating 180° as well, changing its appearance. You may *not* want the gradient to rotate. Which presents other issues, since you can't exclude a gradient fill from rotating. -- This actually looks like it may be more the issue. You'd have to select that "bar" and reverse the gradient after rotation.

Comment: @Scott the left and right side are two diff images intentionally. each image as a whole is moving, when they only need to be rotated. just same person. 

Think of it as left is image A and right is image B - in this case, These images (that are ready as is but not flattened) needed to be duplicated, swapped from AB to BA, and then rotated 180 degrees (for double sided banner prints)

Maybe the various clip groups could be conflicting, maybe the gradient. I don't know, I only have enough knowledge to do what's needed for my job, honestly.

See attached video:
https://imgur.com/a/1LcDRcv

Comment: It's rotating everything, and since you have that odd rotated rectangle sticking above what is visible, that **is** part of the rotation, thus the center of rotation is **not** the center of what is *visible*. The center of rotation is the center of the *bounding area* for all objects. (and it took me a while to realize the image, as a whole was moving up after rotation. You are so close to the project you see it immediately, but it's not immediately noticeable to outsiders.)

Comment: Just a **guess**... but you *might* try ticking `Use Preview Bounds` in the **Preferences** and see if that moves the center of rotation to *just* the preview.

Comment: Thanks Scott, will take a look- I figured could have had something to do with what I saw in the wireframe view but was not sure if anything could be done